# DateTime column in the DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

```
Interventions_df['From DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(Interventions_df['From DateTime'], dayfirst = True)
Interventions_df['To DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(Interventions_df['To DateTime'], dayfirst = True)
```

```
ParserError: Unknown string format: 14-09-2021  10:39:00:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time part is not well formatted `10:39:00:00` (HH:MM:SS:??)

Try:

```
# Regex to match a correct datetime format
pat = r'(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})

#
# I rename 'Inteventions_df' to 'df' for readability
#

df['From DateTime'] = \
    df['From DateTime'].str.extract(pat, expand=False).astype('datetime64')

df['To DateTime'] = \
    df['To DateTime'].str.extract(pat, expand=False).astype('datetime64')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to get rid of this error, you can try to pass the `format` argument in `pd.to_datetime()`, so the parser can recognize the `str` format you are giving. Check [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) of this method for more details and [syntax details](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) that will help you to formulate this `str` argument.